# How could I Segfault without invalid writes?

Tags: c, memory

I am trying to do an implemention of my own malloc and im trying to understand how memory works.

I writed this but I don't understand why I have a segmention fault here :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  char *mem;
  void *maxSize;

  i = 0;
  maxSize = sbrk(0);
  printf("%p\n", maxSize);
  mem = maxSize - 500;
  printf("%p\n", mem);
  while (i != 100)
  {
    mem[i] = 1;
    i++;
    printf("%p\n", &mem[i]);
  }
}
```

When I test this code with valgrind all works fine and I don't have any errors.
But when I am running this code I segfault in the first loop.

Have any idea why ? And do you know how could I get the first free address in my process ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the size of your "unitilized data segment"? I guess it's pretty small, so you will be writing before the start of the data segment. You coud try to increase it first as a check:

```
 ...
 sbrk(1000);
 ^^^^^^^^^^^
 i = 0;
 maxSize = sbrk(0);
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`sbrk` returns a pointer to the start of the memory block after the uninialized data segment. Since you reduce the pointer to 500 bytes left, you most probably corrupt the uninialized data segment within while loop.